# Node.js / VPS - page doesn't show update

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

I've signed up with Digital Ocean to start learning Node.js; I've got it all working but when I change this:

```
res.end('Hello World\n');
```

to this:

```
res.end('Something else\n');
```

and click refresh in FF and Chrome, they both still show 'Hello World', even if I clear the history.

However, when I click [Power Cycle] on my droplet in the Digital Ocean dashboard, the changes are shown when I refresh FF & Chrome.

Any ideas why?

Do I need to configure something on the VPS?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You need to restart the Node process on the server. How are you starting it in the first place? Anyways, test locally; it’ll be a lot faster, and less expensive, too.

Comment: Why didn't you just download Node and learn it on your own machine?

Comment: @false - I went through a long video and he used batch scripts to push file updates to the server and he was using a VirtualBox. I'll check the video again to see which script starts the node server; thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Marty - I did, I played around with VirtualBox & Ubuntu server but wanted to learn on a live site, so I registered a test domain for 50p and bought 3 months of DO VPS for $5 with a coupon code. It's the best £3.50 I've ever spent :)

Comment: Interesting; Is there an advantage vs something like c9.io?

Comment: @Marty - I didn't know about c9 and would have probably have used that instead, but I really like the look of DO, it's got a nice GUI and I can play around for 3 months for $5 with a live production environment before my site deployment. I chose DO because their articles are great and found some informative vids on uTube that used DO.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the problem...

I was using a batch script called deploy.bat that:

- copied any js file updates using WinSCP.exe
- called a restart file with plink.exe to update the server

The restart file had these two lines:

```
sudo /sbin/stop www
sudo /sbin/start www
```

So I was trying to write the updates to my Node server whilst Node was still running (using `ps aux | grep node` to show running processes) and when I tried to refresh my browsers, the updates weren't showing.

If I opened Putty.exe and ran `sudo /sbin/stop www` then made changes to my server.js file and then ran `sudo /sbin/start www`, the updates showed up.

tl;dr - stop server -> update file(s) -> start server